# Using seaborn in apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, seaborn, scatter-matrix

Using pandas and seaborn on a csv dataframe with 50 million cases to make some scatter matrix I noticed that the process times are really long, for convenience I made `df.sample()` on a part of the data and this reduced the process time. Considering the potential of `apache spark` I wanted to ask if it is possible to apply its speed to process all the 50 million data to create: `scatter matrix`, `scatter plot`, `pairgrid` etc. in `seaborn`. Taking information on this topic I saw that it is quite difficult to do this.